# Markdown: is C++ a valid anchor?

Tags: markdown, anchor, stackedit

In Markdown (StackEdit) I cannot create a working `C++` anchor:

```
# Contents
[C++](#c++)                   <-- not working
[C++](#cplusplus)             <-- not working
[C++](#ccc)                   <-- not working
...
## [C++](#contents)           <-- OK
## [cplusplus](#contents)     <-- OK
## [CCC](#contents)           <-- OK
```

Is `C++` a reserved tag?

Comment: Your code works fine, in StackEdit, for me

Comment: @BrandonDyer - Do your links work properly?

Comment: Yes, they do. @Pietro